# Good site to get accurate value of record

Tags: vinyl, record-labels, record

I'm looking to sell records, how can I get good quotes on how much they're worth? I can't find any reliable place.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about locating or naming a particular resource, sound, composition or instrument are often relevant only to the original asker, don't add any value to the stack exchange network & are rarely useful to future readers.

Comment: A Google search turns up numerous sites with records valuations. What makes you think they are all unreliable?

Comment: The https://www.discogs.com/ site includes many features, including a marketplace for buying and selling recordings.  You could check there to get a sense of what prices a given release are listed at.  It's not going to give you one "appraised" price though.  You'll get a bunch of prices from individual sellers.  And often the different version of the same release (even ones with different packaging and the same music) will have different prices.

Comment: @PiedPiper I want one that I can trust enough to buy records based on it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not suitable for this site

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Popsike](https://www.popsike.com/), not sure how active it is anymore but honestly if you find what you're looking for it's great.